# Solidity Contract Deployment fails - but account has plenty of ETH

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, truffle

I was just trying to deploy a new contract on the `Ethereum MAIN-Net` (***not*** `Ropsten`, `Rinkeby` or the other test-nets) - and I’m getting this strange error:

```
Message:  sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx.
The upfront cost is: 159840000000000000 and the sender's account
only has: 158236521250000000
```

The reason I’m finding this strange is cause while I do indeed have only `0.158 ETH` in my account - about $21.60 using today’s rate, which of course isn’t much, those funds should still be ***plenty*** enough for simple contract deployments. Especially considering the following:

-I deployed this very same contract - successfully - to:

1. My local Development Network (`Ganache`) - where the `Total Cost` came back at `0.01332576 ETH` (about $1.80)
2. The `Rospten Network` - where `Total Cost` came back at `0.01342176 ETH` - about $1.83

While I know there's obviously going to be a difference between the various test-nets and the REAL Ethereum Blockchain, it can’t really be like $2 on one and more than $21 on the other, can it? That’s like 1,050% higher.

Is there some other thing going on here that I'm not aware of?

Would really appreciate any insights into what's causing this.

=================================

UPDATE:

As per @smarx suggestion, I'm adding some code & context:

TOOLS:
-I'm using `Truffle` to deploy my contracts.
-Running `ganache` locally on my `MacBookPro`
-Running `Truffle Version` returns:

```
Truffle v5.0.4 (core: 5.0.4)<br/>
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)<br/>
Node v11.10.0<br/>
```

Here's my deploying code - my `truffle.json` file.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');


module.exports = {
    networks: {
        mainnet: {
            provider: function () {
                return new HDWalletProvider(
                    process.env.PRODUCTION_MNENOMIC,
                    "https://mainnet.infura.io/vs/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}",
                    15
                )
            },
            from: "0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            network_id: 1,
            gas: 7992000,
            gasPrice: 20000000000,
            confirmations: 2
        },
        ropsten: {
            provider: function () {
                return new HDWalletProvider(
                    process.env.DEV_MNENOMIC,
                    "https://ropsten.infura.io/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}"
                )
            },
            network_id: 3,
            gas: 8000000,
            gasPrice: 20000000000
        },

        development: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 8545,
            network_id: "*" // Match any network id
        },
    },
    solc: {
        optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 200
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned before, this code worked perfectly on both my local `Ganache` deployment as well as my remote `Ropsten` deployment. I also used this exact same code successfully in the past - as in last week - to deploy contracts to `mainnet`, so I know it has worked and is good for at least some deployments - and I thought it'd be for all of them.

Hope this sheds a lot of light. If more info is needed, please let me know specifics.

======================

UPDATE#2 - thought I'd throw in the exact copy of the error `truffle` is giving me:

```
1_initial_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'Migrations'
   ----------------------
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" could not deploy due to insufficient funds
   * Account:  0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   * Balance:  158236521250000000 wei
   * Message:  sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The upfront cost is: 159840000000000000 and the sender's account only has: 158236521250000000
   * Try:
      + Using an adequately funded account
      + If you are using a local Geth node, verify that your node is synced.

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-deployer/src/deployment.js:364:1
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
Truffle v5.0.4 (core: 5.0.4)
Node v11.10.0
```

Comment: Are we supposed to just guess? You haven't shared anything at all that would help.

Comment: I thought I shared everything that was pertinent, but I'd be happy to share _anything_ you might deem necessary. Can you give some specifics of what you might like to see?

Comment: Your code? Or if you're not deploying with code, the name of the tool you're using? The values you're supplying for the gas limit and gas price? Imagine someone else asked _you_ this question, and think of the first handful of questions you'd ask. Then answer those.

Comment: Maybe a good start would be where you're seeing the error message you shared.

Comment: @smarx I updated the question as per your suggestion.

Comment: @smarx  Also added the exact text of the error `truffle` is showing me...

Comment: the fee is `gas*gasPrice` and 7992000 * 20000000000 = 159840000000000000. Try dropping the `gasPrice` if you need that much gas and want a lower fee! Alternatively, if you used the same `gasPrice` for your previous deployments then you can work out how much gas those deployments required and lower your `gas` level to just above that to get the fee down below your account balance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in your config for mainnet are 7992000 gas limit and 20000000000 gas price, which leaves a tx price of 0.15984 ETH, which your account doesn't have enough for. A tx with a gasPrice*gasLimit+value higher than the accounts balance can't be mined, as it wouldn't have a high enough balance. Try lowering the gas limit to 7000000.

Comment: @ flygoing ok, I was just about to try what you suggested - but then I thought: wait a minute, are you actually telling me that this deployment - of what is a pretty straight forward contract - actually COULD cost me around $20???  That seems crazy. I mean this sort of pricing - its just plain prohibitive.

Comment: I honestly don't remember where I originally got those numbers I'm using (`7992000 gas limit` and `20000000000 gas price`) - and yet they are the thing that's ultimately dictating the price - which seems quite inflated. So is there some reliable tool out there that can estimate the TRUE cost of deploying my contract that I could use to set good working values? Values that will be both high enough to ensure deployment - but also not too high so that I don't overspend?

Comment: It could cost $1000 if you set a really high gas price. It'll only actually cost $20 in the original example if it used all 7992000 gas you let it use, which would only happen if it's a large contract or you're setting a lot of state in the constructor.. Your gas price is also 10x higher than the current average on https://ethgasstation.info/, so you can just lower that to 2000000000 as well.

Comment: That's just how pricing works. A miner picks the transactions to mine by sorting them by gas price. Gas limit is just 21k for normal sends, and you can also estimate the gas for contract calls by calling `estimateGas` in web3.js. You can use ethgasstation.info to get the gas price to use (also convert from gwei to wei, since that's what the value in the config is in).

Comment: Also, since you're using Truffle, you can use migrations to do a dry-run (create the contracts on a fake, local chain), which will show gas usage

Comment: Yeah - I did that. I'm talking about doing the dry-run deployment you speak of. I deployed both locally to `ganache` - and took note of the gas costs there, then deployed it to `rospten` and noted cost again (this info is all in the body of my question, above.) Anyway, I'll definitely try what you're suggesting and let you know how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: Hey that worked! My contract is deployed. Many thanks - will give you credit for right answer. Cheers!